# Can't load images from storage (Laravel)-> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, local-storage, dropzone

Hi everyone I have this problem where I am not able to display the images that I have in the storage folder.
I already connected the storage folder to the public one with the symlink (`php artisan storage:link`) but every time I try to visualize it I get this error from the console:
**`"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"`**

I don't know if this could be useful but here's my ProductController's store function:

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $category = Category::find($request->category);
        $subcategory = Subcategory::find($request->subcategory);
        $product = new Product();
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->availability = $request->availability;
        $product->slug = Str::slug($request->name, '-', 'it').'-'.bin2hex(random_bytes(4));
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->category()->associate($category);
        $product->subcategory()->associate($subcategory);
        
        $product->save();
        $uniqueSecret = $request->uniqueSecret;
        $images = session()->get("images.{$uniqueSecret}", []);
        $removedImages = session()->get("removedImages.{$uniqueSecret}", []);
        $images = array_diff($images, $removedImages);

        foreach ($images as $image)
        {
            $newImage = new ProductImage();
            $fileName = basename($image);
            $newFileName = "/public/products/{$product->id}/{$fileName}";
            Storage::move($image, $newFileName);
            $newImage->file = $newFileName;
            $newImage->product_id = $product->id;
            $newImage->save();
        }
        File::deleteDirectory(storage_path("/app/public/temp/{$uniqueSecret}"));

        return redirect(route('product.create'))
    }
```

and here there is the code of the part of the view in which I recall the images:

```
@foreach ($product->images as $image)
                    
   <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ asset($image['file'])}}" >
   </div>
 @endforeach
```

doing the `dd($image['file']` i get:

```
/public/products/21/vZIxZfm6G8vDgmTv2zfW0aFSbotdnQ4UzWR59oXL.png
```

I tried also to add storage between public and products but it only creates a new folder inside storage/app named storage

(maybe could be useful: I'm using dropzone to upload the images directly from the website and apparently the upload process is working fine)

Don't know what to do to solve this, hope someone could help me, thanks

Comment: did you create the storage symlink using `php artisan storage:link` ?

Comment: yes,I did and I also tried eliminating and recreating it

Comment: Did you checked that the image uploaded successfully?

Comment: Yes, inside the storage folder there's the product, inside it all the folders named with the id of the product and inside that all the images for that product which I am able to open and visualize from vs code

Comment: I guess the `/public` should not be in the image url...

Comment: Nope, if I don't put the `/public` it creates another folder inside storage which is not read by the public one with the symlink, because inside storage there's a public folder and only what is inside that folder could be seen in the real public folder.

Comment: I meant: Is the file accessible if you open it in the browser without /public in the URL

Comment: Yes, i tried without the public in the path and I see it! But I did it manually; how can I make the path from this `/public/products/id/name` to this `/storage/products/id/name` automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
 $imageName = time().'.'.$image->extension();  
 $image->move(public_path('products'), $imageName);
```

and while fetching

```
<img src="{{ asset('products/'.$imageName) }}" alt="Uploaded Image">
```